# Is this sink faucet removable?

Tags: plumbing, faucet, kitchen-sink, replacement

We are trying to replace this sink faucet because the hot water has very little flow. We traced that problem to the faucet itself but now we are unsure if the faucet and handles are removable from the sink basin.

I tried rotating the black parts by hand but was unable to. It is some kind of plastic. I don't know what part the white plastic is from either.

Is anyone familiar with this kind of setup?

[image: sink underside 1]
[image: sink underside 2]
[image: sink topside]

Comment: Never heard of a faucet that was not removable. Am sure this one must be removable.

Comment: "Tried rotating by hand" would be the problem here. You need a wrench. And of course it's removable...

Answer (score 11):

Yes, the faucet can be removed. You have to turn those black "nuts" counterclockwise to remove. You'll need a faucet wrench or a pair of chanellocks to remove them. They will be stuck on there pretty good. The white parts are the thread grabbers. Take the flexible pipes off first.

Answer (score 7):

If you look closely at your first photo, you will see a black plastic nut on the two water line connections.  This is called a "faucet nut".  You will need a "faucet nut wrench" which is available at home centers and other hardware stores.

Comment: Sometimes called a "crow foot" wrench.